# How to add custom payment getaway in woocommerce using Third Party Rest API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Could you please tell me how we can add a custom payment gateway in WordPress using this PHP file or rest API.

```
<?php 

function ProcessRequest($curl_post_data,$service_url,$proxy,$proxyauth) { $output = ''; $certfile       = '/11122333.crt'; $keyfile        = '/11122333.key'; $cert_password = ''; $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url ); curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . $certfile ); curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() . $keyfile ); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); $output = curl_exec($ch); $cblcz = json_decode($output, true ); return $cblcz; } 

$proxy =""; $proxyauth =""; $postDatatoken = '{ "password": "***", "userName": "***" }'; $serviceUrltoken =""; $serviceUrltoken= 'https://sandbox.arbdbank.com:7788/transaction/token'; $cblcz = ProcessRequest($postDatatoken,$serviceUrltoken,$proxy,$proxyauth); 

 $transactionId = $cblcz['transactionId']; 

$serviceUrlEcomm = 'https://sandbox.arbdbankbank.com:7788/transaction/createorder'; 

$curl = curl_init(); 

$postdataEcomm = '{ "merchantId": "11122333", "amount": "100", "currency": "050", "description": "This is test", "approveUrl": "http://localhost/ARBankPHP_1.0.1/approve.php", 
"cancelUrl": "http://localhost/ARBankPHP_1.0.1/cencel.php", "declineUrl": "http://localhost/ARBankPHP_1.0.1/decline.php", "userName": "test", "passWord": "123456Aa", "secureToken": "'.$transactionId.'" }'; 


$cblEcomm = ProcessRequest($postdataEcomm,$serviceUrlEcomm,$proxy,$proxyauth); 

$URL = $cblEcomm['items']['url']; $orderId = $cblEcomm['items']['orderId']; $sessionId = $cblEcomm['items']['sessionId']; $redirectUrl = $URL."?ORDERID=".$orderId."&SESSIONID=".$sessionId; 

?> 

<form id="PostForm" name="PostForm" action="<?php echo $redirectUrl;?>" method="POST"> 

</form> <script language='javascript'>var vPostForm = document.PostForm;vPostForm.submit();</script>
```